# How to create a Windows Service in C++/QT?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, service

I want to create a Windows Service that simply records the screen and sends the recorded file  to a server. But whenever I search Google for Windows Service creation I always get .NET results. How can I make a simple service on anything else but .NET? I will figure out the rest. I prefer Qt or C++ but I can't find anything for them.

Comment: "Anything but" covers too much ground. Pick your poison and go from there.

Comment: I don't recall having much of a problem finding info on raw winapi service creation.

Comment: you can write a windows service using nothing but x86 assembler if you were inclined to that sort of masochism.

Comment: Simply records the screen is going to be complex.

Comment: This complete MSDN example looks non-.NETish: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Qt or C++? Thats kind of paradox

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Qt solves the "simply records the screen" - it becomes a one-liner. It also solves the "send the recorded file to a server" - it takes a couple more lines to do a http post. The real question is: do we really want to help potential script kiddies making malware screen grabbers...

Comment: getting a service to interact with the desktop is not simple in windows. Switch user, remote login, terminal services...

Comment: @KubaOber: Services run in Session 0. They cannot interact with an interactive session. Qt doesn't help here, this simply won't work like this. You'd need a client application running in the interactive session to read its desktop. But then, applications can mark their windows to not be readable by software. Qt doesn't help with this either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [Qt Solutions Archive](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions) you can find the QtService project including examples.

> The QtService component is useful for developing Windows services
>   and Unix daemons.

The component is not maintained anymore but it should still work. The license is BSD-3-Clause.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated the link to the new Github location.

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDH7zWYaScA and works very well on Windows 7 and Windows 10. I used QtService.

You have to include in .pro file:

```
include(..\qt-solutions-master\qtservice\src\qtservice.pri)
```