# Qt application as a system process

Tags: qt

What should I do to install my Qt application as a system not user app?
I try to create an application which will run on Windows Server and need to run while the all users logg off. Is it possible?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478579/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-c-qt) and https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice

Comment: Great :) Happy coding!